# How to put all the special characters and numbers like ( . , ! 1 2 3 4 5 etc. ) under # symbol when creating an A - Z index listing on php?

Tags: javascript, php, css

This is my code so far. And it works just fine but only symbols like . ! shows up too and I want to gather all the posts that starts with `. ! 1 2 3 4` etc. under `#` so when people click on `#` they will see all the posts that are named with words that begins with a special character or number..

Thanx in advance..

```php
<?php
$series = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'post_type'             => _la('series'),
    'orderby'               => 'title',
    'order'                 => 'asc' )); if($series->have_posts()) {echo '<div style="width: 100%;height: 50px;float: left;background-color: #1f2123;padding-right: 20px!important;padding-left: 20px!important;background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);">';

    $letter = '';
    while($series->have_posts())
    {
        $series->the_post();

        // Check the current letter is the same that the first of the title
        if($letter != strtoupper(get_the_title()[0]))
        {

            echo ($letter != '') ? '</ul></li></ul></div>' : '';
            $letter = strtoupper(get_the_title()[0]);
            echo '<div><ul class="buton" style="float:left;padding-left:3px;"><li  style="text-align: center;padding: 0;"><a class="clicker" href="#'.$letter.'" style="display: inline-block;padding: 15px 13px;color: #fff;font-size: 15px;font-weight: bolder;">'.strtoupper(get_the_title()[0]).'</a><ul class="drop gen has-children" style="font-size: 12px;position: absolute;top: 295px;z-index: 1001;display: none;width: 100%;float: left;padding: 20px;margin: 0px;line-height: 20px;background-color: rgb(19, 20, 22);box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 1px 8px inset;">';            
        }

        echo '<li style="display: inline-block;width: 20%;float:left;"><a  href="'.get_permalink().'" class="buttontakvim-link" style="width:90%;text-decoration: none;transition: all .4s ease 0s;color: #d9eafa;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;margin: 0;padding: 0;background: transparent;white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;display:-webkit-inline-box;"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" style="display: inline-block;line-height: 1;text-rendering: auto;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;padding-right: 0.4em;"></i>'.get_the_title().'&nbsp;</a></li>';


    }echo '</div>';}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, your snippet has a lot of unnecessary code. Try cleaning it up a little (remove inline styles, check formatting). And if you answer your own question, even fewer people may look at it because there is already an answer.

Comment: I answered it when people did not look at it but thanx wont do it next time :) inline styles that i put are just to make the current code look good on the page. This code works perfectly but only shows " . 1 2 3 4 etc. " too when falling in line.. a fellow wrote up a code down here and i assume with some knowledge that would have solved the problem for me but i am trying to make it work with my code and did not succeed yet.. Do you have any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: I edited my answer. If it solves your problem you can accpect it as correct.

Comment: thanx ! worked out well for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to group your posts beforehand.

```
<?php
// store all letters from A to Z in an array
$all_letters = range('A', 'Z');

// get all series
$series = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'series',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc')
);

$seriesGroups = [];

foreach ($series as $seriesItem) {
    $first_letter = strtoupper($seriesItem->post_title[0]);

    // check if current item starts with a letter, if not add it to 'special_characters'
    if (in_array($first_letter, $all_letters)) {
        $seriesGroups[$first_letter][] = [
            'title' => $seriesItem->post_title,
            'link' => get_permalink($seriesItem->ID)
        ];
    } else {
        $seriesGroups['special_characters'][] = [
            'title' => $seriesItem->post_title,
            'link' => get_permalink($seriesItem->ID)
        ];
    }
}

// sort items by key
ksort($seriesGroups);

if (count($seriesGroups)) {
    echo '<div class="groups">';

    foreach ($seriesGroups as $letter => $group) {
        echo $letter === 'special_characters' ? '#' : $letter;

        echo '<ul class="dropdown dropdown--' . $letter . '">';
        foreach ($group as $item) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $item['link'] . '">' . $item['title'] . '</a>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer and i am new to this whole php etc. thing so still learning about it :) In your code you wrote all the posts we want to list on $titles right ? But on my website i have so many posts and if i understood it right when i publish a new post it wont automatically go to the listing with your code right ? to sum up: can you write the coding i need using my code as the basic ? It would really help me learn a lot and my website.. thanx in advance :)